# My images disappear when using position relative and absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive, css-transforms

I have this code used for multiple articles and its working fine i think, except when i try to add one special styles for one of the images inside the article by adding style `position: relative` and `id="target"` but then the image widths shrink to 0 or they disappear, I can't tell what kind of mistake i made here. please advise.

try to remove `position: relative` and `id="target"` and see how the code works.

even is there's a better approach to achieve that concept using jQuery or JS please share it.

```css
.article {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}
 
.article-content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 46.66%;
  text-align: left;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.img-control {
  border:1px solid black;
  max-width: 53.66%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: auto;
  width:100%;
}

.img-control img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

img #target {
  transform: scale(2.2) translate(-35%, 29%) rotate(-25deg);
  width: 670px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .article {
    flex-flow: wrap column;
  }
  .article-content, .img-control {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3 class="mainTitle">What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <h5 class="subTitle">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
    <p> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/466x585" width="100%" alt="" style="width: 670px;right: -48px;top: -18px; display: block;position: absolute;" id="target" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say you want a better approach, but where do you want the image ideally?

Comment: If you want to hide the image you could use visibility:hidden on img-control, but it's still not clear to me what your desired outcome is.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I want the image to be inside the container with absolute position so i can make the scale bigger.
and i'm not trying to hide the image

Comment: By the way, depending on how big you want the image next to the banner you can adjust the width in this class : .img-control

Comment: `<img ... width="100%" ... />` probably isn't doing what you think it is. It behaves differently in HTML4 and HTML5. HTML5 expects that value to be in pixels, not %.

Comment: @Arsaar does this work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use absolute positioning you need to have the parent container with either position:absolute or position:relative.

Additionally, in order for an element to occupy the entire height or width of it's parent you need to set the parent's height / width then set the child's height / width to 100% (all available space in the parent). Initially you were setting the image height to 670 so it was exceeding the parent element block [Per Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

> Percentages refer to the width of the containing block

```
    <style>

.article {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.article-content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 46.66%;
  text-align: left;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.img-control {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 20.66%;
  height:156px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.img-control img {
  display: block;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

img#target {
  transform: scale(2.2) translate(-35%, 29%) rotate(-25deg);
  width: 670px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .article {
    flex-flow: wrap column;
  }
  .article-content, .img-control {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}     
</style>
</head>
    <body>
<div class="article">
  <div class="article-content">
    <h3 class="mainTitle">What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
    <h5 class="subTitle">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
    <p> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-control" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/466x585" width="100%" alt="" style="top: -18px; display: block;position: absolute;" id="target" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/zwedj8e1/)

Comment: but that wont work with other articles, if the image is smaller than 30% of the parent container the i will have white space to the right of the image check this [Code here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrLgoE)

Comment: @Arsaar set the width and height to 100% on .img-control img and .image fixes it

Comment: @Arsaar I updated your code pen with the changes I mentioned above: https://codepen.io/jchaplin2/pen/KZJwmP

Answer (score 0):

Your `.img-control` shrinks because its width is not set (`width` and `max-width` are different things).

Also `img #target` shoul be `img#target` without the space. As `img #target` means "element with id='target' within img element", when `img#target` means "img element with id='target'".

And please aviod inline styles, they confuse you and the others.